# Generic project name as output name in WiX

Tags: c#, wix

Is it possible to use the project name of a .net project, as output name, and make it generic, so the same WiX project can be used on multiple .net project??

Currently I have a .wxi (ie. myproj.wxi, myproj2.wxi etc.) file for each .net project, which contains a

```
<?define ProjectReleaseFolder= "MyProject\bin\" ?>
```

I need this path parameter in the .wixproj, to find the assembly file by path in the BeforeBuild event of .wixproj.

Anyone knows?